# Prompt user to save on download from Dropbox

Tags: dropbox, content-disposition, dropbox-api

I want to have a link to download a file from Dropbox that prompts the user instead of displaying the file in the browser. This probably requires setting a content-disposition header to 'attachment'.

I'm currently using the dropbox media URL as described here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#media

It seems my alternative might be to create a proxy, but I'd obviously like to avoid that.

Is there a way to get this behavior from a direct Dropbox link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself.

As documented here:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/201

just add dl=1 to the URL.