# Dropbox: Produce a direct download link [PHP preferred]

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm using the Dropbox REST API and I can successfully retrieve a share url for a file.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#shares

However, the share link takes the user to a preview page on dropbox.com, whereas I'm looking for a direct link that a user could directly download a file. eg. Right click, Save as...

Comment: See my reply here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45190200/2603965

Answer (score 13):

It turns out that the default share url that is returned is a *short url* and the short url will always point to the Dropbox preview page.

Therefore, you need to get the REST API to return the full url by setting the short_url parameter to false. Once you have the full url, then add ?dl=1 at the end of url.

Eg: https://dl.dropbox.com/s/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/MyFile.pdf?dl=1

**More info**:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/201/en

[Prompt user to save on download from Dropbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992284/prompt-user-to-save-on-download-from-dropbox)

**PHP Example**:

This example has borrowed/inspired-by code samples from these:
http://www.phpriot.com/articles/download-with-curl-and-php

http://www.humaan.com.au/php-and-the-dropbox-api/

```
/* These variables need to be defined */
$app_key = 'xxxxxxxx';
$app_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$user_oauth_access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$user_oauth_access_token_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';    

$ch = curl_init(); 

$headers = array( 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT"' );

$params = array('short_url' => 'false', 'oauth_consumer_key' => $app_key, 'oauth_token' => $user_oauth_access_token, 'oauth_signature' => $app_secret.'&'.$user_oauth_access_token_secret);

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.dropbox.com/1/shares/'.$dir );

/*
* To handle Dropbox's requirement for https requests, follow this:
* http://artur.ejsmont.org/blog/content/how-to-properly-secure-remote-api-calls-from-php-application
*/
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,getcwd() . "\dropboxphp\cacert.pem");
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
$api_response = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_exec($ch) === false) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

$json_response = json_decode($api_response, true);

/* Finally end with the download link */
$download_url = $json_response['url'].'?dl=1';
echo '<a href="'.$download_url.'">Download me</a>';
```

Answer (score 2):

just add `?dl=1` at the end of the link

from:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/spfi4x1z600sqpg/background.jpg?dl=0

to:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/spfi4x1z600sqpg/background.jpg?dl=1

Comment: As of august 2017, this does not seem to work anymore. I get the "We'll try to force you to download our app, and create an account"-screen in my browser

Answer (score 1):

Folks looking for a similar solution to get a direct link to download a file that skips the Dropbox download window can use the "Get Temporary Link" endpoint added in version 2 of the API.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-get_temporary_link

> Get a temporary link to stream content of a file. This link will
>   expire in four hours and afterwards you will get 410 Gone.
>   Content-Type of the link is determined automatically by the file's
>   mime type.