# Avoid login using Dropbox chooser?

Tags: javascript, dropbox

I'm using dropbox chooser but the user needs to login first, and I want to avoid this using a *Generated access token* it is possible using only the chooser?. the documentation says:

> By generating an access token, you will be able to make API calls for your own account without going through the authorization flow. To obtain access tokens for other users, use the standard OAuth flow.

but this is only able using the API? or how can I achieve this to avoid letting the user know the password? im only using one single account.

Comment: This may help you "chemi" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29697791/how-to-use-dropbox-chooser-without-forcing-the-user-to-login-to-the-dropbox-acco.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible. The generated access token is for the Dropbox API, which is separate from the Dropbox Chooser. The Chooser is just a pre-built UI component that runs from the official Dropbox web site. The only way for the user to auth to it is by signing in to the Dropbox web site.

If you do just need access to your own account, and not the accounts of your end-users, you should use the API though, e.g., with a generated access token.