# Dropbox file download using php outputs 404 Page not found error

Tags: php, curl, dropbox, dropbox-api, php-curl

Here is the piece of code which my website is using to download pdf files which are available in my Dropbox.

```
        $url = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/abctokenKeyxyz/test.pdf?dl=1';
        $fullpath = '/path/to/dest/';
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        $fp = fopen($fullpath, 'w');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
        $rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
        fclose($fp);
```

It worked fine till yesterday night. But suddenly '404 - page not found error' started appearing inside the downloaded files. The file is still available in dropbox and I haven't changed the permissions. I've even added the redirect options to the php curl but it's of no use.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
```

I am just getting a pdf file with 404 - page not found error printed within it.
When I run a simple linux shell command: `curl -L -o test-pdf.pdf https://www.dropbox.com/s/abctokenKeyxyz/test.pdf?dl=1` it's just working fine.

Well, now I am trying to use Dropbox API to get the file from server and then to save it to the server. But the main challenge I have to face is that I only have the 'Dropbox share url' available with me. Is there anyway to download the file from Dropbox to the server using API just by using the share url? Or is it possible to download the dropbox file by using php curl just by passing the OAuth 2.0 keys and Dropbox file share url ?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115548/dropbox-produce-a-direct-download-link-php-preferred

Comment: @Jah hi, I have already gone through the answer in that post. But there are certain things which I couldn't figure out. 
1) it uses: OAuth 1.0, it's outdated
2) i guess it requires the directory name, '$dir', which i dont have. I just have a share url with me
3) it outputs the download link for the user, I actually need it to be copied down to my server first before letting users download the file

Comment: If running `curl` from the command line still works, then I would expect using `curl` from PHP to still work. Perhaps you can share the exact URL you're using with our support team: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact.

Comment: @smarx i even tried to execute the curl command using exec_shell :
$cmd = 'curl -L -o /path/dest/test.pdf https://www.dropbox.com/s/abctokenKeyxyz/test.pdf?dl=1';
shell_exec($cmd);

But no luck with it either.

Comment: I believe this is being / has been addressed in a support ticket.