# Download file from an specified dropbox account

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

Can I create an application (android, iPhone ... app), which download a file from my own dropbox account? Every App instance will download this file, without authentication. User will no need to have a dropbox account.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is publicly shared, why not? Just use the public URL of the file.

Related Article on how to get a direct download link of a file in Dropbox:

- [Dropbox: Produce a direct download link [PHP preferred]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115548/dropbox-produce-a-direct-download-link-php-preferred)
- [Prompt user to save on download from Dropbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992284/prompt-user-to-save-on-download-from-dropbox?lq=1)

Comment: Thanks. Within direct link, We don't need to use Dropbox API, right?

Comment: @samuel- I want to do the same thing, but I want to implement an onVersionChangedListener to this, so that it downloads a newer version of the file when it changes. Is this possible with this method? If yes then could you please tell me how. One was is to check the entire string in the txt file with the one already downloaded but I'm hoping or something more efficient.